# How do I run an Azure WebJob locally?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I want to create a continuously running WebJob but first I want to try and run it locally for debugging. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have the Azure storage emulator running (I can run the sample for Azure WebJobs in visual studio).

When I run the below it fails on the `new JobHost()` line with:

> Exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: method

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.CallAsync(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("GetNextJob"));
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
    [NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
    public static async Task GetNextJob()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                var log = new Logger();
                log.WriteInfo("Getting next job to be run", 0, 0, "Brain");
                //Console.WriteLine("Getting new Job and putting to que");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
```

Can I even run the continous running jobs locally?

Comment: Question: Wouldn't it be a more flexible way to control the frequency of the method call, to remove the while loop and the sleep timer and then set it up with a cron expression in the Azure dashboard? Then you could control it without re deploying the code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Azure WebJobs are typically just console applications.  You can run it locally just like you would debug, test and run any other console application.  I'd recommend getting the [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk/) and running through the tutorial [Create a .NET WebJob in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/).

Comment: for the sake of completeness, it's not quite true. Azure web job environment is different from your local PC's. Almost all shared resources (registry, graphics, etc) are not accessible: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Comment: Both links now points to the project WiKi. Here is another one which points to the docs and explain how to run the job locally: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started

Comment: The link by @UlyssesAlves takes you to the a Brazilian Portugese page - here's the English equivalent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started and this may also be useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Comment: @avs099 the difference is hardware it is running in, for rest it is pretty much console application and uses Azure Storage to sync jobs. Webjobs running at cloud/Azure does not share local resources.